# Build a php grid with to place information in rows and columns pulled from wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, nested-loops

Hello I'm building a wordpress section in which the information pulled from the database must be displayed in a grid of 3 columns but after rendering in the browser the records are being repeated in each row. Is there anything missing in my code? This has to be the dumbest question ever but I appreciate if someone could help me with this.. :)

Thanks folks

```
<div id="containerTop" class="container">
    <?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query( 'showposts=5' . '&paged=' . $paged );
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        for ( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
            ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); ?>
            </a>

            <?php }?>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
        </div>
        <?php
        };
        ?>

    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what you are doing: for each post, you do a `for` loop of 3 and display the data. What you should do is to increment a count variable for each `while` turn. open a row before the `while` and add a closing after it. When the count goes to 3, end the row and open a new one, put the count to 0 again.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks for the response!!!